# What is the language generated by the following grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Could please tell me the language generated by this grammar?
S->iS |iSeS|ε

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: This is a dump of a problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or about concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 1):

$$\left\{w\in \{i,e\}^*\mid \forall v \sqsubset w\colon |v|_i\ge |v|_e\right\}$$

Comment: Cute. I hadn't seen the notation $\sqsubset$ before. Saves a bunch of text.